# xml / linearlayout not showing properly on device

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm sorry if this question's been asked already but I wasn't able to find any answers. Here's some background context:

I was testing my app on my Nexus 4 to fix some minor bugs. However, just as eclipse was launching it, there was a powercut in the area, switching my computer off. Eventually, once the power restored, I thought I would set a font by .setTypeFace() before running my app again but this made my app crash when I did run it. So after fiddling around with the code and finding no fix, I decided to get rid of the whole font and just run the app with the bug fix. However, this made my app look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euH8M.png).

Now on eclipse, the graphical layout is showing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWFlW.jpg). My app before today was showing like the graphical layout perfectly fine. No errors are showing up on eclipse.

Why has this happened and how do I fix this? Could I have corrupted the whole file?
Thanks.

EDIT: the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/testbg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="33" >

    ---- bunch of textviews ----

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="57" >

    ---- More Textviews ----

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    ---- three buttons ----

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried several of the profiles that the Eclipse plug in has for previews? Does it look right in all of them?

Comment: Yep, it looks fine in all of them

Comment: As far as I can understand your question - your problem is that your Title TextView is being cut off?

Can you post the XML for that element and the Java code used to set/style/change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out - it was the background. I must've obviously messed up the 9.png somewhere because it fixed itself once I got rid of the background.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this happens with my apps when i change the font , some fonts appears like this in the layouts , some play around i use is adding a character or a dot after tab space , and it works , however double check the font issue again ,try to set the font again or to set another font.

Comment: I got rid of the custom font but nothing has changed.